# Execute java (.jar) files in compatibility mode

Tags: java, windows, jar, compatibility

I recently upgraded my laptop to Windows 10 for free. However, I noticed something peculiar yesterday. When opening one of my java projects (a simple chess game), the GUI was a little messed up.

I believe this is due to the upgrade I did on my laptop, because the project worked fine on both Windows 8, 7 and XP.

My question is, how can I run my java project in compatibility mode? This option is available in normal applications when going into the properties on Windows, but I cant seem to find it on java apps.

Regards,
Gomesz.

Comment: You would have to set compatibility mode for the exectuable, java.exe.  Although if you wait a bit Oracle might release a new version of Java that fixes the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried setting the compatibility mode for the java.exe file but it still didn't fix my problem :( I might just have to change my code or wait for a new java version